# How to configure on AWS a closed vpc which can be accessed only through my pc ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I want to launch an instance on AWS which won't have access to the outer network (configure it in a closed vpc), but I want to have the abilities to ssh it and to connect to one of it's ports (let's say port 14000).
what is the simplest way to do so?

Comment: Also make sure that you are using your external IP (unless you have a fixed Static IP allocated to your machine)

Answer (score 1):

The typical solution would require you to setup a bastion host, or jump box, that is only accessible via your whitelisted IP address, and that jump box has access to the machine that you want to protect. The

Lots of articles to be found with google - here is one: https://www.pandastrike.com/posts/20141113-bastion-hosts

and this one directly from amazon: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/linux-bastion/architecture.html

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to attach a security group  to the EC2 instance that has enabled traffic only received from your PCs IP address and port.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it:

1. Create a VPC with a single public subnet.
2. Create a security group in the VPC that allows inbound SSH and port 14000 from your IP address only.
3. Disable all outbound access by removing the All traffic to 0.0.0.0/0 default rule from that security group.
4. Launch an EC2 instance into that public subnet (assigning it a public IP) with the aforementioned security group.